# Is it possible to e.preventDefault in window.onPopState?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, back-button, popstate

I'm trying to stop the user from going back in my web app. For this I tried catching the `window.onpopstate` and added `e.preventDefault` to cancel the back button effect.

But it doesn't seems to happen.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate',function(e){ 
console.log(e); e.preventDefault();  
});
```

Is it not possible to prevent the `popstate` event of browser? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 37):

According to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate), the popstate event is not cancellable:

> Specification: [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-popstate)
>  Interface: PopStateEvent
>  Bubbles:
>   Yes
>   **Cancelable: No**
>  Target: defaultView
>  Default Action: None

Comment: No but you can do:
 window.onpopstate = function (ev) {
               ev.preventDefault();
                    history.go(1);
            };

Answer (score 8):

First off "not possible" is never an acceptable answer.

Secondly you *can* compensate for popstate bugs. In example my rich editor has to constantly compensate for the lazy-bastard key: Backspace. It's not a valid key for a back button (just like spacebar for "page downing") but people impose their personal preferences upon the world instead of adding a browser extension *so* when people press it sometimes the popstate is triggered instead of the editor removing whatever character is to the left of the keyboard caret.

The following code (dependencies in my [platform's documentation](https://www.jabcreations.com/docs/javascript/#functions)) detects when the popstate bug is triggered, slaps it in the face with a `e.preventDefault();` and then fixes the address bar address with `history.go(1);`. The person using the editor doesn't notice anything happened as the browser was not allowed to manipulate the DOM. This code is minimal (other people may be compensating for this bug in various contexts) and I've only tested this in Gecko/Firefox currently so be sure to test Blink, Presto, Trident and WebKit based browsers as well.

```
window.onpopstate = function(e)
{
 if (id_('editor') && is_node_parent(document.activeElement,id_('editor')))
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  history.go(1);
 }
}
```

Comment: 'Not possible' can most certainly be an answer

Comment: I filed a bug on Chrome about the backspace and made a strong case about high risk of data loss and you know what? They listened and took backspace as a back button out of Chrome. After all these years and all it took was to ask. Now if only YouTube would listen about the spacebar...

Comment: related: call `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent subsequently-added popstate handlers from firing too. For instance, if a router listens to popstate and replaces content accordingly, you can prevent it from replacing content.

Comment: The text you insist on re-adding isn't appropriate; stop rolling back.