# I want to write some code on onpopstate event without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am creating the search page for an e-commerce website, where we can search by different facets which creates dynamic URL and I am refreshing views only without refreshing page.
Now if user press back and forth button of the browser, I want to reload views only with relevant data without reloading the page. I am using below code to capture back and forth button event But its reloading page automatically.

Is there any way to prevent this page refresh?

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    console.log("pop!");
    window.getProducts();
    window.getArticles();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
};
```

Comment: which UI framework are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to e.preventDefault in window.onPopState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432296/is-it-possible-to-e-preventdefault-in-window-onpopstate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use h5 history to change url, like this

> window.history.pushState('', '','about');

and add popstate listener to window.